# Consecutive slices of iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice, iterable

Suppose I have an iterator

```
numbers = iter(range(100))
```

and I want to count consecutive mean values and store them in [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) with elements

```
0., 0.5, ..., 49., 49.5
```

this could be done by converting iterable to [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#list)/[`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) and counting its [slices](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) like

```
from statistics import mean

# in cases with large or potentially infinite amounts of data
# this conversion will fail
numbers_list = list(numbers)
numbers_slices = (numbers_list[:end + 1] for end in range(len(numbers_list)))
mean_values = map(mean, numbers_slices)
```

(more info about `mean` function at [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean))

**So my question is more general**: is there any way to get consecutive slices of iterable using standard library without wrapping with `list`/`tuple`?

---

We can write utility function like

```
def get_slices(iterable):
    elements = []
    for element in iterable:
        elements.append(element)
        yield elements
```

and then

```
numbers_slices = get_slices(numbers)
mean_values = map(mean, numbers_slices)
```

but it also looks awful

---

**P. S.**: I know that it will be better to count consecutive mean values like

```
def get_mean_values(numbers):
    numbers_sum = 0
    for numbers_count, number in enumerate(numbers, start=1):
        numbers_sum += number
        yield numbers_sum / numbers_count
```

but it is not what I am talking about.

Comment: So you don't have a `range` object like you originally stated? you can actually index a py 3 `range` object directly without conversion to a `list`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: in my case i have a generator, fixed

Comment: This seems like a case where using a `list` is the best idea, because the iterator is consumed, so you'd have to build a new iterator for every slice. This is possible with `itertools.tee` but likely slow

Comment: The only other way I see is if your generator happens to have a `__reversed__()` method, then you could make the slices in reverse, but I guess it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like there is no standard way of getting consecutive slices of [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) ([iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)/[`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)/[`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)/etc)

so better way i've found out is to use a bit modified utility function from original question

```
def consecutive_slices(iterable):
    elements = []
    for element in iterable:
        elements.append(element)
        yield list(elements)
```

---

**Modifications**:

- added copying of `elements` (btw there are many ways of [doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/5997596)), because previous version in case of wrapping in `list`

  ```
  >>> numbers_slices = list(get_slices(numbers))
  ```

  will give us `list` with `N` repititions of `elements` with all numbers in them (`N` equals to 100 in example):

  ```
  >>> numbers_slices == [list(range(100))] * 100
  True
  ```

---

### Functional approach

After writing a bit more I realized that this can also be done using [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) like

```
from itertools import (accumulate,
                       chain)


def consecutive_slices(iterable):
    def collect_elements(previous_elements, element):
        return previous_elements + [element]

    return accumulate(chain(([],), iterable), collect_elements)
```

here we are prepending empty `list` using [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) as initial slice, which can be ignored in result using `islice` like

```
from itertools import islice
...
islice(consecutive_slices(range(10)), 1, None)
```

but it seems legit to leave it as one slices since empty slice is also a slice afterall.

In comparison with previous solution this is still 4-lines-of-code function that does nearly the same thing, but less "spaghetti" IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an generator that directly `yield`s the means, with local variables containing the running total and count. (Actually you could get the count for free by iterating over `enumerate(iterable)` and adding `1` to the index. Is that enough of a hint?

Comment: counting of mean value and generating of slices should be independent operations in my case

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `itertools.islice`
[Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
import itertools
def get_slices(iterable):
    return map(lambda x: itertools.islice(iterable, x), xrange(len(iterable)))
```

If you don't know the length, here you have a reduce version, highly ineficcient in memory:

```
from functools import reduce
numbers = (number for number in range(1,100))
mean = lambda x, y: (x+y)/float(2)
reduce(lambda x, y: x + [mean(x[-1], y)], numbers, [0])
[0.0, 0.5, 1.25, 2.125, 3.0625, 4.03125, 5.015625, 6.0078125, 7.00390625, 8.001953125, 9.0009765625, 10.00048828125, 11.000244140625, 12.0001220703125, 13.00006103515625, 14.000030517578125, 15.000015258789062, 16.00000762939453, 17.000003814697266, 18.000001907348633, 19.000000953674316, 20.000000476837158, 21.00000023841858, 22.00000011920929, 23.000000059604645, 24.000000029802322, 25.00000001490116, 26.00000000745058, 27.00000000372529, 28.000000001862645, 29.000000000931323, 30.00000000046566, 31.00000000023283, 32.000000000116415, 33.00000000005821, 34.000000000029104, 35.00000000001455, 36.000000000007276, 37.00000000000364, 38.00000000000182, 39.00000000000091, 40.000000000000455, 41.00000000000023, 42.000000000000114, 43.00000000000006, 44.00000000000003, 45.000000000000014, 46.00000000000001, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.0, 60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 69.0, 70.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0, 81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0, 89.0, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 93.0, 94.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0]
```

So, in the end we are doing almost the same as your code, so you should go with it or **use a list instead of a generator ande then use slices of the list (`itertools.ilice`)**.

**EDIT**:
I've been thinking about this, it was easily solved with `Haskell` `scanl`, so I generilezed the concept and get a very good result:

```
def scanl(f, g):
    n = next(g)
    yield n
    for e in g:
        n = f(n, e)
        yield n

list(scanl(mean, number))
[0, 0.5, 1.25, 2.125, 3.0625, 4.03125, 5.015625, 6.0078125, 7.00390625, 8.001953125, 9.0009765625, 10.00048828125, 11.000244140625, 12.0001220703125, 13.00006103515625, 14.000030517578125, 15.000015258789062, 16.00000762939453, 17.000003814697266, 18.000001907348633, 19.000000953674316, 20.000000476837158, 21.00000023841858, 22.00000011920929, 23.000000059604645, 24.000000029802322, 25.00000001490116, 26.00000000745058, 27.00000000372529, 28.000000001862645, 29.000000000931323, 30.00000000046566, 31.00000000023283, 32.000000000116415, 33.00000000005821, 34.000000000029104, 35.00000000001455, 36.000000000007276, 37.00000000000364, 38.00000000000182, 39.00000000000091, 40.000000000000455, 41.00000000000023, 42.000000000000114, 43.00000000000006, 44.00000000000003, 45.000000000000014, 46.00000000000001, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.0, 60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 69.0, 70.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0, 81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0, 89.0, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 93.0, 94.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0]
```

Comment: in my case iterable has no `__len__`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, cant you know the lenght?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, can you iterate several times? or will the iterable be consumed?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, check the edited answer, there you have the solution you were seeking

Comment: `mean` is counted on all numbers and cannot be accumulated without storing previous count, so your `mean` function definition is incorrect

Comment: also your `scanl` is also known as [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, actually YEAH!, forgot about that function in the module, haha. Would you please or answer your own question or should I post it? please

Comment: i will answer myself and hope you will help me